# Updating Dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to have my dictionary continuously update for as long as the loop is running, with the x and y values changing as needed. This is how I initially tried it before getting the error message and coming here.

```
params = urllib.urlencode({'name':'xxxxx', 'pass':'xxxxxxx', 'amount':'x', 'price':'y'})
x = math.floor(first)
y = last*1.007-last*.003
params['amount'] = x
params['price'] = y`
sell = urllib.urlopen("https://sellyourstuffwhatever.com", params)
```

I don't know a whole lot about Python, so I'm sure there is a way to do this. The current method however gives me this error.

> "TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

**Edit:** So I need to be able to update my price and amount every thirty minutes or so, which would be done automatically as the script is looping. The website requires my username, password, price and amount. The username and password never change, however the price and amount do. So is there anyway that I can continuously update them?

Answer (score 4):

[`urllib.urlencode` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) returns a string, not a dictionary. You have to call it after your loop.

Something like:

```
params = {'name':'xxxxx', 'pass':'xxxxxxx'}

for .....:
    params['amount'] = math.floor(first)
    params['price'] = last*1.007-last*.003

params = urllib.urlencode(params)
```

Even better if you use a different variable name for the encoded string.

---

If you don't know much about Python yet, [have a look at some tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/).

Comment: I have been on multiple tutorial sites, it's only after not figuring this one out, that I came here. Anyway, I tried calling it after the loop, and I got the same error. :O

Comment: @Ian: Is there anything else you do to `params`? After you created the string, you cannot assign or read any values from it that way. You have to post more of your code.

Answer (score 1):

[urllib.urlencode](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) returns a string. As strings are immutable objects, you cannot assign a value to a part of it, hence the error.

Anyhow: from your code it seems that you would expect `param` to be a dictionary. Maybe you should clarify your question a bit more...

Comment: I am trying to POST to a website, for as long as my loop runs, however, every 30 minutes or so the price and the amount will change, and so I have to change the parameters to reflect that. I am trying to figure out if there is way to automatically do that, or if I will have to do it by hand every 30 mins.

Comment: @Ian - Just FYI as I see you are new: if you provide more info about your question, is good practice to edit the question itself and leave a comment saying something like "see edit of question" or so. This makes ALL responders get the new info (it's better for you!). Then: in your code you are assigning some value to `params`, you don't use it (as you only assingn values to `x` and `y` and then you try to re-assing values to `params`). There's clearly a mistake here. Can your edit your question explaining step-by-step what you are trying to achieve? (=commenting the code)?